# Is there a CoreLocation notification or delegate method when accuracy improves?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

If you look at a map, the radius of accuracy begins big and then gets smaller as it gets more accurate. But locationManager:didupdateLocations: doesn't get called again when that changes.

Is there something that is called on that event?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `didUpdateLocations:` callback will actually be called again when accuracy is updated. According to this [Apple docs on Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html):

> In addition to a location object’s timestamp, you can also use the
>   accuracy reported by that object to determine whether you want to
>   accept an event. As it receives more accurate data, the location
>   service may return additional events, with the accuracy values
>   reflecting the improvements accordingly. Throwing away less accurate
>   events means your app wastes less time on events that can’t be used
>   effectively anyway.

What sort of tests have you tried to improve accuracy? Did you try it on an iPhone? Did you set the delegate and the `desiredAccuracy` property properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the following code, you will get very frequent location updates.

`self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;`

But according to Apple, it is recommended to plug in the charger to the iOS device while location manager is active. This is because the battery power gets drained fast while getting this much location updates.

There are other levels of accuracy for CLLocationManager( kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation, kCLLocationAccuracyBest, kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer, kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters etc..)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something that is called on that event?

No. You continue to get the same callbacks, but the accuracy of each location is (potentially) improved. There is no callback for "accuracy improved".

The `CLLocation`s you receive in the callback contains vertical and horizontal accuracy information.